How to convert samples received on socket from X300 to a normal complex np array
I am using RX streaming with my X310 to stream received samples to a network destination. When I print the received data, it appears to be in hexadecimal format, but I’m unsure how to interpret or process it. Could someone explain the format of the received samples and how to handle this data? Thank you!
i just received the samples on udp socket in python, and printed it
